# How to make a tablet react only to stylus and not hand touch?

Tags: drawing

I'm trying to learn to draw using tablet and stylus, but I have a problem - when I put my hand on the tablet, it registers it as a touch and makes a curve. It's not very convenient to draw with my hand hanging and me constantly looking if I touch the tablet surface.

Is there a way to make a tablet only react to the stylus and not to hand touch? I'm using the [Honor Pad v6](https://www.gsmarena.com/honor_v6-10253.php) tablet and [Krita](https://krita.org/en/) for drawing - I couldn't find any settings that would do the job.

Comment: The Lifehacks site might have been more suitable.

Comment: What kind of stylus are you using? I [posted an answer](https://superuser.com/a/1594897/167207) that explains the situation, but what you are effectively looking for is palm rejection settings on your device. Short of that you need to physically protect your palm from being detected by the tablet.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be for you to cover the tablet (touching or floating) with another material, and then you would rest your hand on that material.

A drink coaster is the first that comes to mind. A thin book. A kitchen wooden board.

Another tablet, screen-to-screen - just make sure that screens to not touch - otherwise, they will get scratches.

Just look around you and test until you become successful :)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution you may try is an artist glove. Basically, it is a lycra/nylon glove with only two fingers, ring and pinky. It is mostly for preventing smudges but may also prevent the bioelectric conductivity on the tablet.

[image]

[Amazon: Huion Artist Glove for Drawing Tablet](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00VTHAS00)

Comment: this would look ridiculous while making notes in lectures

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what kind of stylus you are using, you might be able to enable palm rejection on your device.

The basic concept of palm rejection is for the system to favor the stylus instead of just any “touch” action. Meaning, it will reject your palm in favor of the stylus.

But in my experience using an iPad mini with an Apple Pencil, this is a feature that is dependent on the stylus. Meaning if you are just using a “dumb” stylus that has no drivers and essentially just mimics a finger touch, you can’t really control palm rejection since the system cannot tell the difference between the touch of your palm versus the touch of the stylus. In contrast if you are using a stylus that has some logic to it — hardware plus drivers — then the system can favor the stylus over any other touch.

That said, you can always use a folded up napkin or some other cloth under your palm to ensure the “touch” of your palm is not detected. This is really a trial and error thing, so experiment with different materials and see what works best for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The primary determining factor here depends on what type of stylus you're using (and what types are compatible with your receiving device, assuming you're willing to purchase a better stylus).

If the stylus you currently use is **capacitative** (also known as "**passive**"), then there's not much you can do about it.  However, note that some devices that accept other types of styluses may also accept capacitative stylus touches as inputs (usually they detect it as just a normal `input touch`), so you should check the capabilities of your input device/receiving device and see if they accept other types of styluses, such as, e.g., **magnetic induction** styluses, etc.  Note that these may be proprietary (in the case of the example I gave, you'd have to get Wacom or Samsung products).